# Iterate over each row and increment the count of the terms associated with the specific researcher in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading a csv file in python that has many disease names in one column and the associated researchers in the other. The file looks something like this -

```
[Table 1]
Terms                    Researcher
1.Asthma                 Dr. Roberts
2.Brochial cancer        Dr. Lee
3.HIV                    Dr.Roberts
4.HIV                    Dr. Lee
5.Influenzae             Dr. Wang
6.Bronchial Cancer       Dr. Wang
7.Influenzae             Dr. Roberts
8.dengue                 prof. christopher
9.Arthritis              prof. swaminathan
10.Arthritis             prof. christopher
11.Asthma                Dr. Roberts
12.HIV                   Dr. Lee
13.Bronchial Cancer      Dr. Wang
14.dengue                prof. christopher
15.HIV                   prof. christopher
16.HIV                   Dr. Lee
```

I want my code to iterate through each row and increment the count of the frequency of a term associated with each researcher so that when the user inputs which term he/she is looking for they should get an output table like this -

```
Term you are looking for : HIV
Names of the researchers                Frequency
Dr. Roberts                             1
Dr. Lee                                 3
prof. christopher                       1
```

Now let's look at what I am doing -

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("Researchers Title Terms.csv")
data.head()
```

which is giving me [Table 1]
and then I am doing this -

```
In[2]:
term = input("Enter the term you are looking for:")
term = term.lower()
list_of_terms = []
for row in data: 
    if row[data.Terms] == term
        researcher1 += 1

    elif data.Terms == term
        researcher2 += 1

    elif data.Terms == term
        researcher3 += 1

    else
        print("Sorry!", term, "not found in the database!")
print("Term you are looking for : ", term)
print("Dr. Roberts:", researcher1)
print("Dr. Lee:", researcher2)
print("prof. christopher:", researcher3)
```

All I am getting here is -

```
File "<ipython-input-9-b85d0d187059>", line 5
if row[data.Terms] == term
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am a beginner in python programming so not quite sure if my logic is entirely wrong or there is really some syntactical error here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. After trying a few things and getting no output I am putting this on the community.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if row[data.Terms] == term:` You are missing colons for `elif` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `groupby` and `value_counts`

Simple and intuitive

```
df.Terms = df.Terms.str.replace('\d+\.\s*', '').str.upper()
df.Researcher = df.Researcher.str.title()
s = df.groupby('Terms').Researcher.value_counts()

s

Terms             Researcher       
ARTHRITIS         Prof. Christopher    1
                  Prof. Swaminathan    1
ASTHMA            Dr. Roberts          2
BROCHIAL CANCER   Dr. Lee              1
BRONCHIAL CANCER  Dr. Wang             2
DENGUE            Prof. Christopher    2
HIV               Dr. Lee              3
                  Dr.Roberts           1
                  Prof. Christopher    1
INFLUENZAE        Dr. Roberts          1
                  Dr. Wang             1
Name: Researcher, dtype: int64
```

You can access the varying terms with `loc` or `xs`

```
s.loc['HIV']

Researcher
Dr. Lee              3
Dr.Roberts           1
Prof. Christopher    1
Name: Researcher, dtype: int64
```

Or

```
s.xs('HIV')

Researcher
Dr. Lee              3
Dr.Roberts           1
Prof. Christopher    1
Name: Researcher, dtype: int64
```

---

### `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
import re

pat = re.compile('\d+\.\s*')
f, u = pd.factorize(list(zip(
    (re.sub(pat, '', x).upper() for x in df.Terms),
    df.Researcher.str.title()
)))

s = pd.Series(dict(zip(u, np.bincount(f))))
```

And you can access the same way as above.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! The only thing is i want to take the input from the user and list only that term that the user wants to look for. The word that user inputs is saved in my variable 'term'. So I am trying --   's.loc(term)' instead of only 's' but getting this as output -- <pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer at 0xa0ca320> Can you help? The entire code -

Comment: `term = input("Enter the term you are looking for:") 
term = term.lower()
data.Terms = data.Terms.str.replace('\d+\.\s*', '').str.upper()
data.Author = data.Author.str.title()
s = data.groupby('Terms').Author.value_counts() /n s.loc(term)`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, when creating an if, elif, for loop, etc. The correct syntax is to have a colon at the end of the initialization line. So in your code you would need to update it to the following:

```
    for row in data: 
        if row[data.Terms] == term:
            researcher1 += 1

        elif data.Terms == term:
            researcher2 += 1

        elif data.Terms == term:
            researcher3 += 1

        else:
            print("Sorry!", term, "not found in the database!")
```

Also, once you correct this, based on your code it looks like you will have a bug as well. You are setting the user input to lowercase but you are not doing the same to the data read from the CSV file. So none of the terms will equal the user input.

Answer (score 1):

read the data into pandas. accept input and then `filter`, `groupby` & `size` gives the desired result

```
term = input("Enter the term you are looking for:")

data[data.Term.str.lower() == term.lower()].groupby('Researcher').size()
# Output with term = 'HIV'
Dr. Lee              3
Dr.Roberts           1
prof. christopher    1
dtype: int64
```

In this method, researchers not associated with a term (i.e. have size == 0) are not shown.

To show researchers with no terms with a count of zero, first set up a dataframe of researchers and outer join the result dataframe with it.

```
researchers = pd.DataFrame({'Researcher': data.Researcher.unique()})
out = data[data.Term.str.lower() == term.lower()].groupby('Researcher').agg({'Terms': 'size'})
pd.merge(reserachers, out, how='outer').fillna(0).sort_values('Terms', ascending=False)
# outputs:
          Researcher  Terms
1            Dr. Lee    3.0
2         Dr.Roberts    1.0
4  prof. christopher    1.0
0        Dr. Roberts    0.0
3           Dr. Wang    0.0
5  prof. swaminathan    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through your dataframe in a similar way as what you are doing, but since you are using `pandas`, it might be worth leveraging `pandas` functions. They are typically much faster than iteration, and the code ends up looking cleaner.

```
term_of_interest = 'HIV'

(df.groupby('Researcher')
 .apply(lambda x: x.Terms.str.contains(term_of_interest)
        .sum())
 .rename('Frequency').to_frame())

                   Frequency
Researcher                  
Dr. Lee                    3
Dr. Roberts                0
Dr. Wang                   0
Dr.Roberts                 1
prof. christopher          1
prof. swaminathan          0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    docs = ["Dr.Roberts",
            "Dr.Lee",
            "Dr.Roberts",
            "Dr.Lee",
            "Dr.Wang",
            "Dr.Wang",
            "Dr.Roberts",
            "prof.christopher",
            "prof.swaminathan",
            "prof.christopher",
            "Dr.Roberts",
            "Dr.Lee",
            "Dr.Wang",
            "prof.christopher",
            "prof.christopher",
            "Dr.Lee"]
    pprint(Counter(docs).most_common(5))
```